# Interval of convergance $\sum_4^\infty \frac{x^n}{n^5}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_4^\infty \frac{x^n}{n^5}$$

I know to use the ratio test on this so I get something weird like this:

$$ \frac{(n+1)^5}{x^{n+1}}\frac{x^n}{n^5}$$

I know that the $x^{n+1}$ will turn into just x but trying to evaluate how an $\frac{(n+1)^5}{n^5}$ behaves is difficult. If I take $\frac{(x+1)^2}{x^2}$ I get what looks like no real pattern for 2,3,4,5 I get

$\frac{9}{4}$$\frac{16}{9}$$\frac{25}{16}$$\frac{36}{25}$

I don't really see a pattern there, the ratio between the two is different and I don't think I can easily pull anything out. How do I compare those terms? I suspect I wasted my time in posting my work because it is so far off as to not even be useful since there is likely an obscure method that perfectly solves this specific case.

Comment: Write it as $(1+1/n)^5$.

Comment: Or try L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: Generally, if you're taking the limit at infinity of a polynomial over a polynomial, just pick the dominant terms on top and bottom. Here on top, the dominant term is $n^5$ (imagine expanding $(n+1)^5$). The dominant term downstairs is $n^5$. Now take the limit of the ratio. The ratio of dominant terms is $n^5/n^5=1$; and the limit is $1$.

Comment: @DavidMitra But others have said it goes to zero.

Comment: ??? Who said that? All the answers show $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{ (n+1)^5\over n^5}=1$, as I stated. (Reckless points out $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{1\over n^p}=0$ for $p>0$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Ratio Test" applied to a power series such as this would produce

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \  \left| \ \frac{x^{n+1}/(n+1)^5}{x^n/n^5}  \ \right| \ = \  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \  \left| \ x \ \cdot \ \frac{n^5}{(n+1)^5}  \ \right| \ = \ | \ x \cdot 1 \ | \ < \ 1 . $$

So the radius of convergence is $ \ R = 1 \ $ .  Since the series $ \ \sum_{n=4}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{n^5} \ $ is an absolutely convergent $ \ p-$ series, the interval of convergence is $ [  -1 , 1 \ ] \ . $

Comment: How is that equal to 1? I proved above that it is not one.

Comment: What is $ \ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{n}{n+1} \right) ^5  \ $ ?  In your post, you haven't shown at all what the limit would be...

Comment: I said that it cannot be evaluated simply because there is no common factor to pull out, nothing cancels.

Comment: How does that prevent you from finding a limit at infinity?  If the denominator is just one larger or smaller than the numerator, what is going to happen to the ratio as $ \ n \ $ becomes larger and larger?

Comment: But how do I prove that? In the book they always reduce it down to some number to prove that it goes to a number by pulling out terms and cancelling, I don't think I can use intuition as proof on a test.

Comment: As other commenters have already remarked here, you can write your limit as $$ \ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{(n+1)^5}{n^5} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{n+1}{n} \right)^5 = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1 +  \frac{1}{n} \right)^5 =  \left( 1 + \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \right)^5 \ . $$  You should have had some time ago a special "limit law" stating that $ \ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n^p} = 0 , $ for any positive number $ \ p \ . $  That gives you the limit for the original ratio as 1 .

Answer (score 1):

Observe that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)^5}{n^5}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^5=\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^5=1^5=1$$

Comment: How is it valid to raise a limit to a power?

Comment: @PaulthePirate Because $x^5$ is a continuous function, for any sequence $a_n$ we have $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n^5=\left(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n\right)^5$.

Comment: Is it proper to just pull out a power like that also? I am not familiar with that transformation, is it always true? Also what happened to your x?

Comment: @PaulthePirate For any continuous function $f(x)$, if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n$ exists then $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f(a_n)=f\left(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n\right)$$ In this case we are using $f(x)=x^5$.